# iOS AirPlay Action Sheet for public app store publishing - like in Spotify

Tags: ios, spotify, iphone-privateapi, airplay

I've been working on a project that involves AirPlay endpoint selection and was wondering how the guys at Spotify had done the following in-app selection of the available AirPlay endpoints (you can see an AirPlay icon/message at the bottom of the app that when tapped brings up a similar Action Sheet to what you'd see via the Control Center):

[image: Spotify AirPlay Action Sheet]

From what I know, the only "public" API one may use for this kind of thing is [MPVolumeView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPVolumeView_Class/index.html) which is not necessarily the same, as it'd show a volume controller and a button to trigger such action sheet.

The [following blog](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2012/04/23/ios-mirroring-and-programmatic-airplay-selection/) talks about a [MPAudioVideoRoutingPopoverController](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MPAudioVideoRoutingPopoverController.h) which is a private API, so wondering if that's what the folks at Spotify are using and if so, why was such thing allowed on the store? (I thought use of private APIs was strictly forbidden by Apple's rules)

If the private route is the only way to achieve it, is there any particular way to do it in a way that Apple would be ok with? ie: like mentioned in an answer to [iOS: Airplay picker MPVolumeView alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23007498/ios-airplay-picker-mpvolumeview-alternative) around messing with the `MPVolumeView` and either triggering the UI from there while hiding the rest of the elements?

Comment: I'm wondering is all they're doing is rendering an `MPVolumeView` without the slider and with a custom icon like described on [this other blog post](http://blog.denivip.ru/index.php/2012/12/airplay-and-hdmi/?lang=en).

Answer (score 0):

[This other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13262514/what-is-the-code-to-call-the-actionsheet-airplay-directly) provides an alternative to the approach still using the `MPVolumeView` class but invoking the touch of the button inside it programmatically while hiding all (or most) of the interface.